# Add a VPN connection unavailable in Ubuntu 16.10 on a Lenovo x1 Carbon

Tags: vpn, 16.10, openvpn

When I click the wifi/network icon in the top right, and go to VPN Connections > Add a VPN connection - this option is greyed out for me. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been reported elsewhere (and I experience it myself). I'm not sure of the cause. But you can add VPN connection information by going down to 'Edit Connections' instead. Some have reported that as being a successful workaround for them.